# Service layer, implement timed cache

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, .net-3.5

So right now I have come into a project that I'm taking over the responsibility for.

One part I found that is halfway implemented is a service layer cache. Apparently this cache in the service layer was implemented to avoid a high amount of calls do the database cluster. The service layer is hosted on two servers for performance and stability if one server goes down.

Now to my problem, or rather, what is the best pattern for the implementation of a timed cache? Objects that rarely changes or are updated, like countries etc are cached and never really released if not the pool is reset.

Because we, or rather my predecessors, have two active services on two separate machines I'm thinking about implementing a timed cache. 
An alternative could be to have the services talk with each others but of course taking into account that they are not dependent on each others so that if one goes down the other will work just fine.

Right now there are 12 dictionaries with items that are cached. Most of these are rarely updated. These dictionaries resides in one class that is not a singleton but is implemented as a singleton so it is only instantiated once.

How do you advice me to solve this interesting problem and why that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not setup a cache cluster consisting out one or multiple servers, using one of the following caching technologies:

- [Windows Server AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849.aspx)
- [NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/)

This way you don't have to worry about running two services doing the same thing.

Both these technologies support caching object for a specified about of time.

E.g.:

```
public void Add(string key, object value, TimeSpan timeout)
{
    //...
}
```

Or you can choose to cache them indefinitely.

Redudancy is supported. Be aware of the small print though.

[AppFabric Redundancy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747219/appfabric-redundancy)

Back in 2010 I wrote some posts about AppFabric and NCache.

- https://github.com/geersch/AppFabric
- https://github.com/geersch/NCache

Both provide an easy and similar API to work with.

Answer (score 1):

[MemCached](http://memcached.org/) is another. MemCached is targeted at distributed architectures such as the one you describe. I use an adapter written by [Paul Glavic](http://weblogs.asp.net/pglavich/) He's written post [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/pglavich/archive/2010/10/13/caching-architecture-testability-dependency-injection-and-multiple-providers.aspx) which demonstrates how to use it.

Glavs adapter will allow you to switch out caching implementations in the future from Aspnet caching to MemCached or AppFabric.

The adapter also provides a nice API in the form of the ICacheProvider:

```
var data1 = cacheProvider.Get<SomeData>("cache-key", DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), () =>
{
    // With the cache disabled, this data access code is executed every attempt to
    // get this data via the CacheProvider.
    var someData = new SomeData() { SomeText = "cache example1", SomeNumber = 1 };
    return someData;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net already have a quite nice caching system built in. Is there a reason you cannot use that?

It supports timed flushing of the cache, flushing by external events, it can be configured to use memory, a database, a separate cache server, a distributed cache and so on. The should be no reason for you to make your own :-)

Comment: I inherited this project so I don't know why they did as they did. I'd like input on which choices I have available from other experienced users and why. Systems I've built before has not had the need to have much caching at all. When one page is loaded one or two calls are made and that results in the same amount of database calls. Here one page load results sometimes into several calls with more database calls making for a lot of db calls and that I was told is why they did this form of caching that is now implemented.

Comment: Well, the need for caching depends on how much traffic you expect. If this is a low-traffic solution then caching just complicates things in my opinion.

Comment: Since caching is an optimization technique you might want to build the solution without it and then add caching later on wherever it is needed. That way you don't have to guess on which parts of the solution performs good or bad.